# Look up and replace values in a list (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list

```
z = ['111111','222222','333333','4444444']
```

and I want to look up each item in z and replace it with the equivalent value in stored in my dataframe 'data', which has two columns, old numbers and the new numbers:

```
old_numbers = data.ix[i, 'old_ids']
new_numbers = data.ix[i, 'new_ids']
```

Example: the old number 111111 in z needs to be updated to 121212, and 222222 needs to be changed to 202020, so I need to look up 111111 and 222222 from z and find it in the old number column my dataframe, then replace it *within the list z* with 121212 and 202020 respectively:

```
# pseudocode: 
print z
>>> ['121212',222222','333333','444444']
for each number in z:
  if number is in old_numbers column in dataframe:
    replace number with equivalent new_number from new_numbers column in dataframe
print z
>>> ['121212',202020','333333','444444']
```

What's the most efficient way to replace the old numbers in z with the new numbers by looking up the old number in a dataframe and getting the corresponding new number?

Comment: is your `z` list much bigger than `data` DF?

Comment: No, but I have lots of small z lists for each product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mapping using a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(df.old_ids, df.new_ids)}
z_new = [d.get(k, k) for k in z]

>>> z_new
['121212', '202020', '303030', '4444444']
```

Note that the `d.get(k, k)` defaults to the original value if no lookup value is found in `df.old_ids`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Pandas power for that:

```
In [109]: z = ['111111','222222','333333','4444444']

In [110]: df = pd.DataFrame({'z': z})

In [111]: data
Out[111]:
  new_ids  old_ids
0  121212   111111
1  202020   222222
2  303030   333333
3  404040  4444444

In [112]: df
Out[112]:
         z
0   111111
1   222222
2   333333
3  4444444

In [118]: dict(data[['old_ids','new_ids']].values)
Out[118]:
{'111111': '121212',
 '222222': '202020',
 '333333': '303030',
 '4444444': '404040'}

In [119]: df.replace(dict(data[['old_ids','new_ids']].values), inplace=True)

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
        z
0  121212
1  202020
2  303030
3  404040
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, but I'm getting a 'None' for df.replace(dict(data[['old_ids','new_ids']].values), inplace=True). I'm querying the old ids and new ids - does it matter what data type? I set them to strings but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
for index, i in enumerate(z):
    if i in old_numbers:
        z[index] = new_numbers[old_numbers.index(i)]
```

This won't work if you have duplicates in old_numbers, as index only returns the first match.