# Doing a lookup using dataframe.get

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a list, `tids`, containing track IDs. that I to do a lookup of those track IDs onto the a dataframe, `res`, and give me back a list of track titles instead.

I was basing my code on the one given here: [Look up and replace values in a list (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291706/look-up-and-replace-values-in-a-list-pandas)

But it was simply giving me back the track ID again.

I then tried tweaking the code as below but this gives me back a dict within a list it seems (so the print [0] at the end there seems to return everything). I can of course then play with this to extract just the track titles but was wondering what I'm doing wrong in my approach?

```
def convertTrackIDToTrackName(dbPath, tids):
    con = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
    sqlStr = "SELECT track_id, title from songs"

    # Load into Pandas
    res = pd.read_sql_query(sqlStr, con)
    con.close()
    res = res.set_index('track_id')


    z_new = [res.get('title',t) for t in tids]
    print (z_new[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series`, `map`, and `tolist`:

```
s = pd.Series(tids).map(res['title']).tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Slight typo in .tolsit() there by the way.